# Is "unanimous consensus" correct phrase?

Tags: collocations

Is it OK to say:

> We can't reach a unanimous consensus on the issue.

Does `unanimous consensus` make sense? I know from the dictionary that *unanimous* collocates with *agreement* but I didn't find *Unanimous consensus*. Which one is better?

- Unanimous consensus
- Unanimous agreement

Comment: **consensus** is very often used to mean "wide but not unanimous agreement" or "agreement by a large majority with only few dissenters".  *The consensus among scientists is that human activity is a major factor contributing to global-warming.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unanimous agreement is better. Consensus is general agreement, whereas unanimity is complete agreement. Do not mix the two.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consensus is general agreement which means there is unanimity in a group.

Answer (score 0):

consensus is unanimous. Unanimous consensus is **redundant**.

unanimous agreement is OK because one can say partial agreement, complete agreement, a majority of persons in agreement (majority agreement).

We can't reach a consensus on this issue.
We can't reach unanimous agreement on this issue.

Comment: So cold you please tell me which adjectives collocate with consensus in order to emphasize it?

Comment: I would change the wording: Quite simply, consensus has eluded us.

Comment: Consensus is _not_ synonymous with "unanimity".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  I didn't say that. I said if there is a consensus, then there is unanimity. That's true. However, a consensus can be qualified, in which case, there is no unanimity.

Comment: I think you just contradicted yourself.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey No, I did not. Merriam Webster: ***Definition of consensus 
1a : general agreement : UNANIMITY***
[caps not mine]